# Dismiss popover when UISearchBar is pressed

Tags: iphone

I have a popover presented from a UIBarButtonItem.  In the same UIToolBar, there is a UISearchBar.  I cannot figure out how to dismiss the UIPopoverController when the searchBar is selected.  I didn't see any properties on the UISearchBar, or see anything in the delegate method itself, but maybe I missed it :-.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to store a pointer to the popover manually

Comment: can you explain a little further?  i do have a pointer to the popover in my class where both the searchbar and popover get presented.  but i don't know what action/event, there is when the search bar is selected.

Comment: [popover dismissPopoverAnimated: NO]; does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

By "search bar is selected" - do you mean a user-event? Are you looking for the UISearchBarDelegate callback methods?  Like -searchBarSearchButtonClicked  or -selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange.